# How can I print something if an item is in a list?

Tags: python, list

I am new to python so don't be *facepalm* if you see something that is so easy to solve...

What `if` condition I need to use to make the print run in the following bit of code I've tried so far (which doesn't work):

```
Music=["Play Some Music","Open Music","Music","Play"]

Action=(input("Please Select An Action To Do: "))

if Action==Music:

    print("Here Is Your Music")
```

Comment: *facepalm*... ok `if Action=="Music":` is probably better

Comment: Or `if Action in Music:` (Note don't capitalise your variable names)

Comment: You're checking if a string equals a list exactly. Not part of the list. That'll never be true

Comment: Chris_Rands, thank you very much I never thought of "in" , it actually worked. I will also stop capitalizing the words, to be 100% sure of future issues.:D

Comment: not capitalising words @3vil Its about not to capitalise variables!! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you don't want to check whether the Action is the same as Music list, but only if it is **in** the Music list, use the `in` operator:

```
if Action in Music:
```

Also, as mentioned in comments, use lower case for variables in python - `action` instead of `Action` and `music` instead of `Music`. It doesn't matter for the interpreter, but this is the convention, and it will make it easier to work with other people, and easier for them to understand and help you.

Comment: Talking about case, it might also be wise to lowercase both the comparison strings and the input if `"music"` or `"MUSIC"` should match as well.